# Como implementar Bootstrap 4 no Angular CLI

Tags: angular, bootstrap-4, angular-cli

Não estou conseguindo utilizar o Bootstrap com o Angular CLI. Estou utilizando o ng-bootstrap e estou seguindo todas as recomendações do site, porém sem exito, alguém conhece como utilizar?

> instalação via npm:

`npm install --save @ng-bootstrap/ng-bootstrap`

> importando no módulo principal, com o .forRoot():

```
import {NgbModule} from '@ng-bootstrap/ng-bootstrap';

@NgModule({
   declarations: [AppComponent, ...],
   imports: [NgbModule.forRoot(), ...],
   bootstrap: [AppComponent]
})
export class AppModule {}
```

> importando no módulo com o componente que estou utilizando:

```
import {NgbModule} from '@ng-bootstrap/ng-bootstrap';

@NgModule({
   declarations: [OtherComponent, ...],
   imports: [NgbModule, ...]
})
export class MeuModule {}
```

Comment: "***porém sem exito***" ... Descreva seu problema! Pois alguém pode fazer o teste e funcionar.. Então está retornando algum erro ?

Comment: Não retorna nenhum erro não, só não funciona nenhum CSS do Bootstrap. Nenhum estilo.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Você precisa adicionar o *Bootstrap* em seu projeto:

```
npm install bootstrap@4 --save
```

depois editar o arquivo **.angular-cli.json**:

```
"styles": [
    "styles.css",
    "../node_modules/bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css"
],
```

> Fonte: [ng-bootstrap's css folder does not exist](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49729226/)

Answer (score 0):

Ok. O problema aqui é que te esqueces-te de adicionar *o css* ao teu themese :D

no teu `main.scss` (ou equivalente) só tens que importar o scss do bootstrap:

```
// main.scss

// 3rd party libraries
@import "~bootstrap/scss/bootstrap";
```

e os estilos do bootstrap passam a estar na tua folha de estilos

Answer (score 0):

Use o comando `npm install bootstrap --save`, e adicione a linha:

```
"../node_modules/bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css"
```

como no exemplo abaixo:

```
"build": { 
    "options": {
        "styles": [
            "../node_modules/bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css",(adicionar essa inha no angular.json)
            "styles.css"
        ],
    }
}
```